# SQL Pivot in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a SQL table with information about email campaigns that my company has created. Each line of the table is an action that a user has taken on a specific campaign:

| User ID | Campaign Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Campaign#1 | opened |
| 01 | Campaign#1 | clicked |
| 01 | Campaign#2 | opened |
| 02 | Campaign#1 | opened |
| 02 | Campaign#2 | opened |

I wanted to Pivot this on SQL, in a way that would render the unique number of people who have opened and clicked on each campaign:

| Campaign Name | Opened | Clicked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Campaign#1 | 2149 | 122 |
| Campaign#2 | 4223 | 141 |

I've been trying to work with:
SELECT user_id, campaign_name, status from `table`
PIVOT(
COUNT (DISTINCT user_id)
FOR status IN
( [opened],
[clicked]
) ) AS PivotTable

But then I am getting:
**Unrecognized name: opened at [5:6]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below example

```
select * from your_table
pivot (count(distinct UserID) for Status in ('opened', 'clicked'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select '01' UserID, 'Campaign#1' CampaignName, 'opened' Status union all
  select '01', 'Campaign#1', 'clicked' union all
  select '01', 'Campaign#2', 'opened' union all
  select '02', 'Campaign#1', 'opened' union all
  select '02', 'Campaign#2', 'opened' 
)
```

the output is

[image]

Comment: Ah. I didn't realise something: the Status column is a nested column - so basically I have properties.status, properties.country, properties.campaignname, etc.

Therefore the error I am getting is: Error running query Column raw_properties of type STRUCT cannot be used as an implicit grouping column of a PIVOT clause at [2:1]

Comment: That's alright, don't worry, it makes sense that you answered the original question as it was. Will post a new one.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Consider also voting up the answer :o)