# Pivoting columns from STRUCT type

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a SQL table with information about email campaigns that my company has created. Each line of the table is an action that a user has taken on a specific campaign:

| UserID | properties.CampaignName | properties.Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Campaign#01 | opened |
| 01 | Campaign#01 | clicked |
| 01 | Campaign#02 | opened |
| 02 | Campaign#01 | opened |
| 02 | Campaign#02 | opened |

I wanted to Pivot this on SQL, in a way that would render the unique number of people who have opened and clicked on each campaign:

| CampaignName | Opened | Clicked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Campaign#01 | 2149 | 122 |
| Campaign#02 | 4223 | 141 |

My initial thought was to use the PIVOT query:

```
select * from table
pivot (count(distinct UserID) for properties.Status in ('opened', 'clicked'))
```

But I didn't realize something: the `CampaignName` and Status columns are nested under the "properties" column - so basically I have `properties.status`, `properties.country`, `properties.campaignname`, etc. Therefore the error I am getting is:

```
Error running query Column raw_properties of type STRUCT cannot be used as an implicit grouping column of a PIVOT clause at [2:1]
```

Comment: looks like the sample data / table structure you provided is not what you actually have  - can you please update your question with correct information, so we are not wasting our time to figure out what exactly your case is!

Comment: Have you trying using [unnest](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest_operator) to get your data? otherwise your sample data is not matching what you are suggesting. Maybe you can provide us with a complete image of your working table.

Comment: no images please! can you imagine we will provide answers as an image of code? will it be helpful?

Comment: Hello, @MikhailBerlyant. Thanks for noticing, I've corrected it. Let me know if this is OK now.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
select * from (select UserID, properties.* from your_table)
pivot (count(distinct UserID) for Status in ('opened', 'clicked'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select '01' as UserID, struct('Campaign#01' as CampaignName, 'opened' as Status) as properties union all
  select '01', struct('Campaign#01', 'clicked') union all
  select '01', struct('Campaign#02', 'opened') union all
  select '02', struct('Campaign#01', 'opened') union all
  select '02', struct('Campaign#02', 'opened') 
)
```

output is

[image]

So, technically this is exactly the same answer that I already provided you with - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70115346/5221944 - you just needed to flatten struct into separate columns first

Comment: Hello, Mikhail - thank you and we seem to be getting there :)
One thing that doesn't seem right is that the output is rendering a lot of lines where CampaignName contains the same value, and on each line I have either a  "1" value for "opened" and "0" for clicked, or vice-versa. It doesnt seem to be grouping all the opens and all the clicks for every CampaignName.

Comment: No, sorry but you haven't answered. The output is very different from the image you posted - I don't have a value bigger than "1" on any of the lines.

Comment: have you tried with the data that you provided in your question and is used in my answer? or you are applying it to something else?! As I mentioned  - i can only see what is in your question - and solution is for it, not for whatever real use case you have! and btw, I just double checked and i am getting whatever output i presented in my answer! so try to find what it is that you do different from what you see in answer!

Comment: I am sorry, looks like you know how to help, but you're looking after "votes up".

Comment: Please read my comments again!! I am not mind-reader! I can see and help ONLY with what is in your question, not what is in your mind! as of "vote ups" - this is a part of game called SO - and yes, I like when my answers got voted up! :o)

Comment: last attempt: can you just copy paste CTE and code in my answer and just simply run it w/o changing anything, so we can try to locate where you break it?

Comment: I am sorry. I did what you suggested and I created a new question - it's here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309288/pivoting-columns-from-struct-type-complex-schema

Thank you, Mikhail

Answer (score 0):

You can still use your PIVOT clause, the deal here is with the struct values. So my approach was to unnest that data and set is as same level data and then proceed to reuse your query. Below are the steps I follow:

**working table**

```
create table `project.dataset.table`(
    userid INT64,
    properties STRUCT<CampaignName STRING,Status STRING>
);
```

**dummy data**

```
INSERT INTO `project.dataset.table`(userid,properties) VALUES(01,STRUCT("Campaign#01","opened"));
INSERT INTO `project.dataset.table`(userid,properties) VALUES(01,STRUCT("Campaign#01","clicked"));
INSERT INTO `project.dataset.table`(userid,properties) VALUES(01,STRUCT("Campaign#02","opened"));
INSERT INTO `project.dataset.table`(userid,properties) VALUES(02,STRUCT("Campaign#01","opened"));
INSERT INTO `project.dataset.table`(userid,properties) VALUES(02,STRUCT("Campaign#02","opened"));
```

**query**

```
with campaign_unnest as (
    select o.userid,
    prp.Status,prp.CampaignName
    from `project.dataset.table` o, unnest([o.properties]) as prp
)
select * from campaign_unnest pivot (count(distinct userid) for Status in ('opened', 'clicked'))
```

**output**

| CampaignName | Opened | Clicked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Campaign#01 | 2 | 1 |
| Campaign#02 | 2 | 0 |

Let me know if this answer fits what you are trying to achieve. If not, please let me know so I can update my answer.
For reference I use the google bigquery documentation about [arrays & structs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays), [unnest](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest_operator) and [with](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause).