# Pivoting columns from STRUCT type (complex schema)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working with a table called "Campaigns". It has a bit of a complex schema:

| Field name | Type | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| internal_customer_id | STRING | NULLABLE |
| type | STRING | NULLABLE |
| ingest_timestamp | TIMESTAMP | NULLABLE |
| timestamp | TIMESTAMP | NULLABLE |
| properties | RECORD | NULLABLE |
| properties.campaign_name | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. variant_id | NUMERIC | NULLABLE |
| properties. action_id | NUMERIC | NULLABLE |
| properties. action_type | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. variant_type | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. new_choice | BOOLEAN | NULLABLE |
| properties. variant | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. campaign_id | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. integration_id | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. subject | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. message | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. type | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. integration_name | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. campaign_policy | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. action_name | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. consent_category | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. status | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. language | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. message_id | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. recipient | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. sent_timestamp | NUMERIC | NULLABLE |
| properties. sending_ip | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. country | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. city | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. ip | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. latitude | NUMERIC | NULLABLE |
| properties. state | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. user_agent__a510e506 | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. longitude | NUMERIC | NULLABLE |
| properties. code | NUMERIC | NULLABLE |
| properties. cumulative | BOOLEAN | NULLABLE |
| properties. url | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. xpath | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. valid_until | NUMERIC | NULLABLE |
| properties. attempts | NUMERIC | NULLABLE |
| properties. status_code | NUMERIC | NULLABLE |
| properties. audience_id | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. integration_type | STRING | NULLABLE |
| properties. operation | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties | RECORD | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. campaign_name | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. variant_id | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. action_id | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. action_type | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. variant_type | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. new_choice | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. variant | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. campaign_id | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. integration_id | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. subject | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. message | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. type | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. integration_name | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. campaign_policy | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. action_name | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. consent_category | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. status STRING | NULLABLE |  |
| raw_properties. language | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. message_id | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. recipient | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. sent_timestamp | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. sending_ip | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. country | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. city | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. ip | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. latitude | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. state | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. user_agent__a510e506 | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. longitude | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. code | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. cumulative | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. url | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. xpath | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. valid_until | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. attempts | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. status_code | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. audience_id | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. integration_type | STRING | NULLABLE |
| raw_properties. operation | STRING | NULLABLE |

The field "properties.status" can have different values - "opened", "clicked" and a few other values that are not relevant at the moment. Bringing context to my question - this is a table that stores information from user's activities on the emails that we send to them. Every time a user opens and clicks on an email, a row is created on the table. So if the user opens the same email 3 times, we will see 3 lines with the same information "properties.status = "opened".

I want to use just a few fields from this column, and most importantly I want to see how many USERS have opened and clicked each of our emails. Bring this to SQL, I would like to count the distinct "internal_customer_id" for when the status was "opened" and "clicked", grouped by Campaign Name. So what I'd like to see as an output is:

| Campaign_Name | Subject | Opened | Clicked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I did try to Pivot, as you can see on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272876/pivoting-columns-from-struct-type/70295022) but the output is that for every opened and for every click, I have one line in the table where Opened = 1 and Clicked = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you are looking for below

```
select * from (
  select UserID, 
    properties.CampaignName, 
    properties.Subject, 
    properties.Status 
  from your_table
)
pivot (count(distinct UserID) for Status in ('opened', 'clicked'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mikhail. It worked perfectly now.