# GROUP BY a value that is not part of the query's filter

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with information from email marketing campaigns. On that table (you can see the schema [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309288/pivoting-columns-from-struct-type-complex-schema/70310677)) I have several different columns about the users who received this campaign. One of the most important columns from this table is properties.status, because it's where I can get information about user's interactions with our campaigns.

So, for example, if the email has been sent to the user, a row is created on that table and the value for the "properties.status" column is "enqueued". If the user opens the email, another row is created but the value now is "opened". If they click, value for properties.status is "clicked", etc.

I am trying to generate a query that will have as the output the total number of people who have opened and clicked on every campaign that we sent.

I did manage to pivot "Opened" and "Clicked", as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309288/pivoting-columns-from-struct-type-complex-schema/70310677). But now I have a new challenge.

I want to group everything by the month where the emails were sent, so basically having an output:

| Month* | Campaign_Name | Subject | Opened | Clicked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

- Month would be (MONTH FROM timestamp AT TIME ZONE "UTC")

What's being challenged for my is that I want to group the timestamp column when the campaign.status was delivered, but "opened" and "clicked" are other values for properties.status.

I tried to do:

```
WITH
  ORCTOR AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      internal_customer_id,
      properties.campaign_name,
      properties.Subject,
      properties.Status
    FROM
      `project-id.exp_1ddb4cbe_fc04_11ea_9874_06183dd6fcf3_views.campaign` ) PIVOT (COUNT(DISTINCT internal_customer_id ) FOR Status IN ('opened',
        'clicked')))
SELECT
  CONCAT( EXTRACT (MONTH
    FROM
      timestamp AT TIME ZONE "UTC"), "/", EXTRACT (YEAR
    FROM
      timestamp AT TIME ZONE "UTC") ) AS Sent,
  properties.campaign_name, opened, clicked
FROM
  `project-id.exp_1ddb4cbe_fc04_11ea_9874_06183dd6fcf3_views.campaign`
WHERE
  properties.status = "enqueued"
```

But then I get:
Unrecognized name: opened at [20:29]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below

```
select * from (
  select UserID, 
    extract(month from timestamp) as Month,
    properties.CampaignName, 
    properties.Subject, 
    properties.Status 
  from your_table
)
pivot (count(distinct UserID) for Status in ('opened', 'clicked'))
```

Comment: The query does run with no error, but returns nothing:
https://imgur.com/8KS1erK

Comment: hard to say anything more without any solid data example. you do not need to use whole real schema of your table - just use only fields/columns which matter - create some dummy sample so we can work further on your issue :o)

Comment: Btw, if you carefully see the screenshot that you provided - you will see that you’ve got 1322 rows!!!!!

Comment: Dear Mikhail, you were right! A couple of days later I tried again and it worked perfectly.. same number of rows, but this time around I could actually see the output. Guess it was a temporary bug on BQ? Thanks anyway :)